# Netty cannot send second request in a channel

Tags: java, netty

I tried to simulate http handshake in netty but client cannot send second request.
This is the flow

```
Client -> request1 -> Server
Client <- response <- server
Client -> request2 -> Server (cannot see data is sent)
Client <- response <- server
```

Here is the code
https://github.com/Tonghua-Li/Netty-Handshake-Test/tree/master/src/main/java

Server and client logs are in the root folder of git repo
https://github.com/Tonghua-Li/Netty-Handshake-Test/blob/master/client.log

From log, request 2 is prepared and flushed to port 80 (server). but I don't see hex block in the client log as request 1

```
sending request 2
Sep 24, 2019 6:02:40 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler flush
INFO: [id: 0xd6797f27, L:/127.0.0.1:60893 - R:/127.0.0.1:80] FLUSH
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `FullHttpRequest` instances or you need to "terminate" your `HttpRequest` with a `LastHttpRequest` before you send the next `HttpRequest`.

If you attach a `ChannelFutureListener` to the `ChannelFuture` returned by `writeAndFlush(...)` you will see that the `ChannelFuture` failed as the "sequence of messages" is not what is expected.